# Monitor BIOS activity

Tags: bios, malware

As I read today, Secret services are able to infect the BIOS of almost every computer using different methods. Is there a way to find out if this has happened on my Ubuntu notebook, for example monitoring the BIOS activity?
Greetings

Comment: This should probably be posted on superuser.com rather than askubuntu.com since it's not specifically related to Ubuntu.

Comment: This really isn't on-topic here.. but take a look at this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/how-to-check-the-integrity-of-my-bios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html  suggests you password-protect your BIOS. Then, enter an *incorrect* password once and record the checksum error.

Periodically thereafter, enter an incorrect BIOS password and compare the checksum. If it differs from the original, your BIOS has been altered, and redownloading it from the manufacturer's website and reflashing it will recover from whatever tampered with it.